# change text color in pinescript code problem

Tags: pine-script

I have this code in pine script:

```
labelTpSl(entry_y, "enter " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(entry_y)), color=color.new(color.blue,100))
```

How i can change color for text the color in code for label?

Answer (score 0):

`labelTpSl()` is a custom function but it must have a `label.new()` inside of it.

`label.new` has an argument called `textcolor`. You can use this to set the text color.

> label.new(x, y, text, xloc, yloc, color, style, textcolor, size,
> textalign, tooltip, text_font_family) → series label
>
> ***textcolor (series color)*** Text color.

Comment: labelTpSl(entry_y, " Entry: " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(entry_y)), color=color.new(color.blue,100))
labelTpSl(stop_y , " Stop Loss: " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(stop_y)), color=color.new(color.red,100))
labelTpSl(tp1_y , " Take Profit 1: " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(tp1_y)), color=color.new(color.green, 100))
labelTpSl(tp2_y , " Take Profit 2: " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(tp2_y)), color=color.new(color.green, 100))
labelTpSl(tp3_y , " Take Profit 3: " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(tp3_y)), color=color.new(color.green, 100))

Comment: I HAVE MANY LABLE

Comment: Doesn't matter. You should use the `textcolor` argument of the `label.new()` function.